# Quais são os formatos utilizados para se representar valores (cor, contraste, brilho) em imagens digitais?

Tags: imagem, processamento-de-imagens, bitmap, compressão-de-imagem

O que quero é: reconhecer padrões de pixels em um arquivo, ou saber como o assembler trata isso (para justamente facilitar reconhecer estes padrões).

Sempre quis criar alguma aplicação para manipular imagens, fazendo reconhecimento de objetos, tentativas de novas técnicas de *chroma key*, etc. É possível por exemplo, saber as o que uma cadeia de bytes escritas em ASCII significa, mas não sei como são escrito os pixels.

E nunca encontrei nenhum material falando do funcionamento dos bytes ou pixels de uma imagem em baixo nível. Saber como é tratado em assembly pode ajudar.

Minhas tentativas foram: abrir o bitmap em um programa de leitura binária, aonde não encontrei um padrão, e tentei o básico também tentando abrir em um interpretador de ASCII, aonde foi pior.

Se eu conseguir descobrir como encontrar estes padrões de pixels, eu poderia usar qualquer linguagem que manipula arquivos (mesmo em alto nível) para reescrever pixels. Ou criar algum algoritmo de reconhecimento facial, etc.

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia do que eu devo pesquisar já agradeço!
Para ser justo, achei dois ótimos materiais na internet:
Uma questão próxima a isso no Yahoo respostas
https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111021192959AAUuYZ5
Uma biblioteca gráfica que já usei para programação de games
http://www.unidev.com.br/index.php?/topic/54321-gdi-setpixel-em-baixo-n%C3%ADvel/

Porém, preciso mais do que isso!

Espero que minha dúvida enriqueça a curiosidades de muitos!

Comment: Tem que ser em assembly? A tag não condiz muito com o que você pede no texto. Além disso, uma coisa é manipular bitmaps em memória, outra é salvar e ler de arquivos - frequentemente são formatos diferentes.

Comment: Olá Paulo, bem vindo ao SOPT. Antes de mais nada, saiba que este site não é um fórum. Sua pergunta precisaria ter uma dúvida mais objetiva. Se não fez ainda, faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Quando vc diz " [...] material falando do funcionamento dos bytes ou pixels de uma imagem em baixo nível." O que vc quer dizer com "baixo nível"? Apesar de mencionar assembly, o restante da pergunta parece indicar que você quer saber quais são os **formatos** comuns de armazenamento de imagens. Se for esse o caso, sugiro dar uma olhada aqui: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_file_formats

Comment: O formato bitmap é razoavelmente bem especificado. Veja [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) e [aqui](http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm), por exemplo. De todas as formas, **já existe muita coisa pronta** para o que você quer fazer. Vc já tentou estudar um pouco de [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), por exemplo? Uma sugestão de link que pode servir como boa introdução: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Hb7ZFSYqnk

Comment: A manipulação de bitmaps em memória de trabalho é irrelevante no momento, uma vez que o texto indaga sobre manipulação de arquivos. Assembly é uma linguagem de montagem, considerada de baixo nível, pois ainda que seja legível a humanos, faz comunicação direta com os dispositivos, uma vez que a maioria das arquiteturas tem sua própria versão de assembly, e seus respectivos drives para comunicação. Portanto, o tópico não só trata de assembly, como também drives escritos sobres. O ponto é: para que quero isso.
Se conhece maneiras de fazer o quero em nível mais alto, gostaria que compartilhasse.

Comment: Paulo, eu realmente não entendi a sua dúvida. Vc agora menciona "drives para comunicação". Pergunta se alguém conhece "maneiras de fazer o que quer" em mais alto nível... Mas o que você quer?! Não está claro. Tente editar a pergunta e deixá-la mais focada. Seria o seu desejo simplesmente saber como ler/gravar um arquivo bitmap em assembly?

Comment: Se você quer manipular arquivos de imagens e imagens em memória são irrelevantes a você, então porque o assembly? O assembly na prática só vai manipular imagens em memória e quase ninguém vai se preocupar em usar assembly diretamente para ler ou escrever em arquivos, vez que isso é algo que linguagens de alto nível conseguem fazer com excelência.

Comment: Isso foi em resposta ao usuário Victor Stafusa sobre contestar sobre o uso da tag assembly. Não é uma explicação da minha dúvida.
Mas se não está clara minha dúvida, eu vou tentar especular o que possivelmente não ficou claro. Se você poder adiantar que parte, vai ajudar a eu editar e melhorar minha pergunta.

Comment: Paulo, a questão que eu estou colocando é que saber em assembly **não vai te ajudar**. Os algoritmos para ler e escrever imagens em PNG, GIF, JPG, TIF, PCM, PCX, TGA, BMP ou o formato que você preferir não tem relação com o assembly e podem ser utilizadas quaisquer linguagens de programação para manipulá-los. Em especial, assembly seria uma das piores escolhas possíveis para isso porque não é lá muito portável e compiladores são capazes de escrever assembly muito melhor que a maioria dos humanos conseguiria. [continua]

Comment: [continuação] Normalmente esses algoritmos são implementados em C, mas já vi serem feitos em Delphi, em Java e em Python também. O assembly seria útil talvez na parte de drivers, mas os drivers não manipulam arquivos, eles manipulam apenas bitmaps em memória que você deixou bem claro que não são o seu interesse.

Comment: Ah, e se você quer fazer coisas como reconhecimento facial, o melhor seria ler o arquivo, colocá-lo na memória e fazer o reconhecimento direto na memória. O motivo disso, é que em vários formatos de arquivo, os pixels não estão codificados lá diretamente. Por exemplo, o JPG usa uma técnica matemática bem complicada chamada de [transformada rápida de Fourier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_r%C3%A1pida_de_Fourier) para fazer compactação e reduzir o tamanho do arquivo. Por outro lado, descompactado na memória, ele estará em um formato de fácil manipulação para o que você quer.

Comment: Não. Reconhecimento facial (no sentido do que quero) é apenas umas das possíveis vantagens extras (que você explicou que não seria vantajoso dessa forma).

Comment: O que quero é: reconhecer padrões de pixels em um arquivo, ou saber como o assembler trata isso (para justamente facilitar reconhecer estes padrões). 
O que posso conseguir com isso..........coloco aqui as possibilidades....!
Eu não consigo ser mais claro. Estou me esforçando!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51437/discussion-between-paulo-sergio-duff-and-victor-stafusa).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Para imagens em memória, existem vários formatos possíveis, basicamente de acordo com o número de bits por pixel, que em geral pode variar de 1 (preto ou branco) até 32 (8 para o vermelho, 8 para o verde, 8 para o azul e 8 para o *alpha*). Os mais comuns são:

- 1 bit por pixel - Preto ou branco.
- 2 bits por pixel - Preto, branco e 2 tons de cinza.
- 4 bits por pixel - 16 tons de cinza.
- 8 bits por pixel - 256 tons de cinza.
- 2 bits por pixel - Preto, branco, ciano e magenta.
- 2 bits por pixel - Preto, branco, verde e vermelho.
- 4 bits por pixel - 16 cores básicas escolhidas de acordo com uma palheta de cores. Normalmente essas cores são preto, branco e dois tons de cada uma dessas cores: cinza; azul; vermelho; verde; amarelo; ciano e magenta.
- 8 bits por pixel - 256 cores escolhidas arbitrariamente de uma palheta/tabela.
- 16 bits por pixel - Capaz de representar 65536 cores distintas. Desses bits, temos 5 para o componente vermelho, 6 para o componente verde e 5 para o componente azul. A ordem dos bits pode ser RGB (vermelho-verde-azul) ou BGR (azul-verde-vermelho).
- 24 bits por pixel - capaz de representar 16777216 cores distintas. São usados 8 bits para cada componente de cor. A ordem dos bits pode ser RGB ou BGR.
- 32 bits por pixel - Igual ao caso dos 24 bits por pixel, mas acrescentando um byte para representar a transparência, ou mais precisamente o *alpha*, que é a opacidade, o oposto da transparência. Um *alpha* de valor zero indica total transparência, enquanto que um *alpha* de valor máximo (255 neste caso) indica uma cor totalmente opaca. O conceito de transparência/opacidade é útil quando você quiser desenhar imagens umas sobre as outras. A ordem dos bits pode ser ARGB, RGBA, ABGR ou BGRA.

Os formatos em arquivo tais como PNG, GIF, JPG, PCX, BMP, TGA, TIF, PGM, PPM, PBM, etc são muitas vezes compactados e nem todos representam os pixels diretamente. Eles tem largas diferenças entre si e cada um tem um formato único e bastante diferente dos demais. Por exemplo:

- Alguns formatos, como o BMP, o PGM e o PPM, representam os pixels diretamente e de forma sequencial.
- O PNG usa uma compactação com algumas similaridades com o ZIP.
- Há formatos (por exemplo, GIF) onde há um cabeçalho com uma palheta/tabela de cores e cada cor é um número de 0 a 255 de acordo com a tabela. Neste caso, podemos ter 0=azul, 1=laranja fosforescente, 2=verde musgo, 3=dourado... Dependendo de como está a tabela.
- Transmissões de TV analógicas utilizam dois componentes para cores (crominância) e um para o brilho (luminância), para ser compatível com formatos de TV preto-e-branco que só tinham o brilho. [Esse mesmo conceito é usado também no JPG](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Photographic_Experts_Group#Algoritmo).
- Há formatos que usam algumas técnicas matemáticas bem complicadas que surgem da necessidade de se representar informações que representam ondas (com frequência, amplitude e fase) na forma de pontos discretos e compactos. Disso advém a [transformada rápida de Fourier](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_r%C3%A1pida_de_Fourier) e a [transformada discreta do cosseno](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformada_discreta_de_cosseno). Elas são frequentes na conversão de formatos analógicos para digitais e também para espremer o máximo possível de informações sobre a imagem na menor área possível. [O JPG, por exemplo, utiliza a transformada discreta do cosseno](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Photographic_Experts_Group#Transformada_Discreta_do_Cosseno).

Assim sendo, tratar os pixels diretamente em muitos desses formatos é difícil, e convém muito mais você ler os arquivos, convertendo-os em bitmaps diretamente na memória e então manipular esses pixels diretamente na memória.

Na prática, não vale a pena se preocupar muito com os formatos dos arquivos, vale mais a pena utilizar uma biblioteca pronta para ler e escrever imagens nesses formatos e se preocupar então apenas com os bitmaps em memória.

Como o colega Luiz Vieira mencionou em comentários, o OpenCV é uma biblioteca bem rica e amplamente difundida que já tem muitas dessas coisas já prontas para se usar.

Comment: Eram essas informações que você e o Luiz me passaram que estava procurando. Isso já me dá muito para começar. Muito obrigado Victor!

Comment: Apesar da pergunta não ter sido tão clara, a resposta foi realmente muito boa e útil. :)

Comment: O BMP é o formato mais fácil de interpretar (já consegui uma vez) : http://dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/bmp/bmpfileformat.htm Se puder linkar na resposta, agradeço